# Use of name as a verb

Tags: expressions, idioms, verbing

I heard these lines in the movie **Minions**. They go like

> **Stuart:** "Scarlet."
>
> **Scarlet:** "Don't you Scarlet me backstabbing little traitors."

The name **Scarlet** is used here as a verb. What do this mean and how in other ways can names be used as part of speech other than noun?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many proper and common nouns in English could be used as a verb. One simple example is

> A: What can I do for you, sir?
>
> B: Don't **sir** me. I don't like being called "sir". It makes me feel old!

The sentence in your example could be rephrased to:

> Don't you (dare) call my first name (as if you were my close friend), backstabbing little traitors.

First names are usually used among close friends in casual settings. Scarlet doesn't want Stuart to consider her as a friend (as she considers him as a traitor). That's what "Don't Scarlet me" basically means.

The question and answers posted on ELU, [“To science the sh*t out of something”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/305782/to-science-the-sht-out-of-something) will be helpful.

Comment: @Aman - it's not just names - [we have a habit of turning many nouns into verbs in English](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/the-basics-of-verbing-nouns/).

Comment: @stangdon Wonderful! That was very useful. I think I should **bookmark** the website. And I think the **bolded** words are the things I learned from this question's answers and comments.